# Find the exponent of a function

Tags: functions, polynomials

I want to find the highest exponent of a function. Here is my code:

```
T22 = -x - x^5;
T23 = x^2 + x^6 - x^8;
V[n_] := (x^(3 n - 8) + (-1)^(n - 1) x^(n - 4))/(x + x^-1) T23 + (
    x^(3 n - 7) + (-1)^(n - 2) x^(n - 1))/(x + x^-1) T22;
```

Now I want the the highest exponent of `V[4]`, then I input the code:

```
Exponent[V[4],x]
```

The output is $12$. It's not the right answer. The right answer is $11$. I have not figured out why the output is not 11. Thank you!

Thank Jose for the previous problem. Now I make a replacement:

```
a = V[4] /. x -> (E - 1)/2 y + (E + 1)/2;
Exponent[FullSimplify@a, y]
```

Still, the output is 12, not 11. Since the replcement is a linear transformation, the highest exponent of $a$ should not change. Again, thanks.

Comment: You should simplify `V[n]` first. This works `Exponent[Simplify@V[4],x]`

Comment: It works,thank you.

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas Turn your comment into a simple answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Simplify` first `V[n]` :

```
Exponent[Simplify@V[4],x]

(* 11 *)
```

Comment: So the function should be simplified at first, then simplify the $V[n]$ for the specific number $n$.  I should simplify  each expression for each step, right? thanks again.